# Two dimensional array and it's matrix representation convention

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array, computer-science

Let's say I have a two dimensional array [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] (javascript syntax).  When I write this down as a matrix on paper, should it read like:

```
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

OR

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Basically, should the first level be represented horizontally or vertically?
Is there a convention on this?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on whatever matrix you're trying to model, and if it's layout is 3x2 or 2x3?

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, it is not possible to represent multiple arrays as columns:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6]] // two arrays, one containing 1-3, the other 4-6

[[1, [4,
  2,  5,
  3]  6]] // three arrays: [[1, [4, 2, 5, 3], 6]]
```

Comment: What about [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]?